# Python is inconsistently creating folders when I try to untar .tar.gz files

Tags: python, gzip, tar

I have a directory full of .tar.gz files that I am looping through and untarring using the following python function:

```py
def untar_file(source, dest):
    """Untars a .tar.gz file

    Args:
        source (string): Where the .tar.gz file is located
        dest (String): Where the untarred folder will land
    """
    with tarfile.open(source) as tar_object:
        tar_object.extractall(dest)
```

I was taking the tarred files and untarring them from a folder called "IN" to a folder called "UNTARRED". Inside the folder UNTARRED this function was creating new folders with the same name as the .tar.gz files in "IN", but without the ".tar.gz" extension. The content in the .tar.gz file was inside the new folder in UNTARRED.

Seemingly all of the sudden the function stopped creating a folder in UNTARRED and dumping the contents of the .tar.gz file into that folder and instead just started dumping the content of the .tar.gz file into the UNTARRED folder.

The strange thing is that this seems to happen to only some of the .tar.gz files. Others work just fine. I don't know why it works the way I want it to for some .tar.gz files but not others.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: This is due to the way that the tar files are being tarred, not your un-tarring process. The files must be tarred with all data inside a folder in the root of the tar for it to untar in the 'correct' way that you describe. If files are tarred directly into the root directory, that is how they will be untarred.

Comment: The tar files are being sent to me by someone else. Are you saying that they need to make sure they are creating them correctly and the issue is happening not because there is an problem with my code?

Comment: Yes, they need to generate their files more consistently.

Comment: If you open those files graphically in a program like 7zip, you should be able to see the difference in the structure

Comment: I just found out that the person sending over the tar files is creating them inconsistently. Some contain subfolders while others do not. That is the cause of my issue.

I need to get consistent data.

Thanks.